# How to pull json data from a URL into a table in vuejs or a dropdown

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to pull json data array from a url and using it to populatea table or a dropdown using vuejs and axios.
This is the link I want to pull the data from. How do I do this? https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos.

Comment: please share the code that you've tried so far

Comment: This is where my code that i havetried is. https://codepen.io/asmafayaz1992/pen/LYPxrOe

Comment: Your js is borked (You have a data fn inside your data fn). See it fixed [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/pozPVjW).

Comment: How do I do this for a dropdown menu and once selected added to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data object add `todos_users` array :

```
    data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      todos: [],
      users_todos:[]
    }
```

Your axios request should be like :

```
 axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos?page=1')
      .then(response => {this.users_todos = response.data})
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
```

and finally the template :

```
  <tr v-for="todo in users_todos" v-bind:key="todo">
            <td>{{ todo.userId }}</td>
            <td>{{ todo.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ todo.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ todo.completed }}</td>
              <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
```

the [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/dybWeyL?editors=1011)

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me.

Comment: How do I do this for a dropdown menu and once selected added to the table?

Comment: Please post another question in which explain your issue and please provide code details

Comment: Its the same code.